# Why doesn't this Bash for loop script work?

Tags: bash

I have an bash script such like below. What I am trying to do is to replace the first column of each `FILEIN` with value `$c` excluding the header row (first row), but it doesn't work and output file `FILEOUT` is same as `FILEIN`. I can't figure out what's wrong in the script. Somebody has some suggestions?

```
# /bin/bash

for pheno in ldl vldl 
do
    echo "..processiong $pheno"
    for c in {1..22}
    do  
        echo "..processiong chr$c"
        FILEIN=UVASET2_white-${pheno}_chr${c}.tsv
        FILEOUT=UVASET2_white-${pheno}_CHR${c}.tsv
            awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {if(NR>1) $1=$c; print}' $FILEIN >$FILEOUT
    done
done
```

[image]

The first column should be `5` in the above output rather than `---`.

Comment: You need to pass the variable. See duplicate

Comment: learn the difference between single and double quotes.